# I am trying to follow NetBeans naming conventions, but it won't compile?

Tags: javafx-2

The setters with the int values say int cannot be dereferenced, and string value cannot find the method. I may not understand completely, but they look fine to me.

Please advise, thank you!

```
    private void setMachineID(int machineID) {
        machineID.set(machineID);
    }

    public int getMachineID(){
        return  machineID.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty machineIDProperty(){
        return machineID;
    }   
}
```

Comment: try to remove final key word

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same identifier for the fields and the method parameters.

If there are more than 1 variable with the same identifier visible in a part of the code, java will use the one that is declared "closer" to this part of the code.

In this case the scope of the method parameter is the method which is "closer" to the method body than the fields. For this reason you must tell java explicitly that you want to use the field, not the method parameter.

You need to add change your setters like this:

**Before**

```
private void setMachineID(int machineID) {
    machineID.set(machineID);
//  ^^^^^^^^^                    references method parameter
//                ^^^^^^^^^      references method parameter 
}
```

**After**

```
private void setMachineID(int machineID) {
    this.machineID.set(machineID);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                    References field
//                     ^^^^^^^^^      references method parameter 
}
```